# PHP - collect same array values

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array 
`array ( 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 1, 1, 5 )` and I need to collect same array values and divide it to different arrays. So after this action from this array I should have 4 different arrays:

```
array ( 1, 1, 1 )
array ( 2, 2 )
array ( 5, 5, 5 )
array ( 4, 4 )
```

what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Take a look at `array_count_values()`, that should get you almost there: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = [];
foreach (array_count_values($values) as $value => $occurrence) {
    $result[] = array_fill(0, $occurrence, $value);
}
```

This assumes that the individual value identity doesn't matter, i.e. that you don't have objects whose individual instance you need.

Though I'm not sure why you'd need that particular array format then in the first place. Just use the result of `array_count_values`.

Comment: thanks, very comfortable solution

Answer (score 2):

```
$input = array ( 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 1, 1, 5 );
$output = array();

foreach ($input as $value)
   $output[$value][] = $value;

var_dump($output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make another array, with the distinct values as the array keys.

```
<?php

$array = array(1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 1, 1, 5);    
$result = array();

foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (!isset($result[$val])) { // Check if the index exists
        $result[$val] = array();
    }

    $result[$val][] = $val;
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
<?php
    $a  = array ( 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 1, 1, 5 );
    $a = array_count_values($a);
    $arr = array();
    foreach($a as $k=>$v){
        for($i = 0; $i < $v; $i++){
            $arr[$k][] = $k;
        }
    }
    print_r($arr );
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 4
    )

)
```